# How to give same rank to rows with same data in some columns then increase when data changed SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, dense-rank

I am trying to use Dense_Rank in my SQL Query to rank rows with same data in some columns, and then increase it when changed data is found in next row. I was successful in doing so by this query:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY ID, Date1) AS P_Key, 
   *
FROM dbo.tbl_Main T
ORDER BY S_ID, ID, Date1, Date2;
```

But the Rank is not coming in the sequential order and is coming according to the order applied on main sql. The output of the script is:

[image]

As visible from the screenshot, it is giving the same rank(P_Key) to the rows which have same data in ID and Date1 columns, but is out of sequence everywhere due to main Order By. I want other rows to be appeared in the same sequence as applied by main "Order By" and the sequence of "P_Key" to be started from 1 and then increasing sequentially. How can I do so?

Comment: Could you add some sample data that explains the desired output? It's a bit difficult to understand what it should look like.

Comment: @jpw Please refer the Fiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4aac0/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ORDER BY for DENSE_RANK unless and otherwise you provide the columns to sort inside ORDER BY of DENSE_RANK. The other way that could be done is using a `CTE` or `Derived tables`. It can be done by following

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY ID, Date1) AS P_Key,*
    FROM MyTable T  
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY P_Key,S_ID, ID, Date1, Date2
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/310036)**

Comment: This query is not giving my desired result. ID with '100045' should come first, but its coming after '100018'. Please look at my fiddle, it is giving the desired result except incorrect sequence of P_Key column.

Comment: I made some changes in your query and it is giving me the desired output. `;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY S_ID, ID, Date1) AS P_Key,*
    FROM MyTable T  
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY S_ID, ID, Date1, Date2`

Comment: I have written query which sorts `P_Key` followed by the other columns. If you need to filter `S_ID` or `ID` first, then that should be the first columns in `ORDER BY`. @Hemant Sisodia